# Youtube API and javascript questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I know this has to be totally ghetto, but I'm trying to figure out how to get a feed of my youtube links to display on my homepage in a somewhat stylish fashion.  I get tired of having to post something on youtube, then create a post on my website that is basically a duplication of the youtube post.  Perhaps there is already something out there that has this functionality built in, but so far I haven't seen it.  I have a couple questions about what I'm trying to accomplish thus far:

1. How can I update my code so I can use 'this' in my youTubeMe object verse having to reference the variable name.  I'm pretty sure I understand why I can't use it how I'm doing it currently, but I don't know how to fix?
2. Second, the google api seems a bit weird to me.  I'm not too stoked about using iFrames and the split operation I have to do in order to get the VideoId can't be correct.
3. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I'll post the code, but you can also find a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/keroger2k/JZrDy/9/)

HTML:

```
<div id="pager">
</div>
<div id="player">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        youTubeMe.init();
    }

</script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var youTubeMe = {
    pageSize: 10,
    player: null,
    startIndex: 1,
    username: 'google',

    init: function() {
        $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/' + this.username + '/uploads?alt=json&start-index=' + this.startIndex + '&max-results=' + youTubeMe.pageSize, youTubeMe.createYouTubePlayers);
    },

    createYouTubePlayers: function(data) {
        $('#player').empty();
        $('#pager').empty();
        if (data.feed.entry.length < youTubeMe.pageSize) {
            youTubeMe.createPreviousButton();
        } else {
            if (youTubeMe.startIndex !== 1) {
                youTubeMe.createPreviousButton();
            }
            youTubeMe.createNextButton();
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '195',
                width: '320',
                videoId: data.feed.entry[i].id.$t.split('/')[5]
            });
        }
    },

    createNextButton: function() {
        $('<a id=\"next\" href=\"#\">next</a>').appendTo('#pager');
        $('#next').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            youTubeMe.startIndex += youTubeMe.pageSize;
            youTubeMe.init();
        });
    },

    createPreviousButton: function() {
        $('<a id=\"prev\" href=\"#\">prev</a>').appendTo('#pager');

        $('#prev').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            youTubeMe.startIndex -= youTubeMe.pageSize;
            youTubeMe.init();
        });
    }

};
```

CSS:

```
iframe { margin: 20px; }
#pager { background-color: #666; line-height: 3em; text-align: center; }
#pager a { color: #fff; font-size: 1.8em; margin: 0 15px; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you should go is create a closure and have everything contained in that. You can do it like this:

```
//a closure function that calls itself
(function(){

    //with var it would be private and not accesable like this: 
    //youTubeMe.pageSize
    var pageSize = 10;

    //declare a global reference to the youTubeMe object
    var youTubeMe = window.youTubeMe = function(){

    };

    //with youTubeMe.* it is accessable from anywhere in your page
    //you can either
    //declare a public variable like this
    youTubeMe.player = "youtube player";
    //or a public method like this
    youTubeMe.foo = function(){
        //this "this" here is your youTubeMe object
        console.log(this);
        bar();
    };

    //like the private variable at the top, this function is private
    //and can only be called from inside the youTubeMe object   
    function bar(){
        //this "this" here is the window
        console.log(this);
    }

})();


console.log(youTubeMe.player); //out puts youtube_player 
youTubeMe.foo(); //outputs the youTubeMe object
youTubeMe.bar() //throws an undefined error
```

As for the youtube api; I've always found it to be really good. I've never used the iframe embed just because "iframe embed" sounds not right to me. If you use the [youtube api](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) you have two options: [Embedded player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#player_apis) or the [chromeless player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#player_apis). Take a look at the embedded player because unless you want to build a custom skin for your player, its the way to go. Creating a playlist becomes easy when you use the api because you let javascript do all the playing and playlist stuff.

Hope that helps.